# Rename EXE's from multiple directories w/ batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

Can someone help me make my batch file more efficient?

Right now I have one giant script with all of the exe names individually spelled out. As the environment grows, this will become harder to manage. What I'm looking for is something like this:

**Folder structure:**

```
- Folder 1: Contains NewExe.exe (new version of my executable) and ClientName.txt files which contains the names of all my clients
 - Folder 2: Some clients reside here
 - Folder 3: Some clients reside here
 - Folder 4: Rest of the clients reside here
```

**Process:**

1. Check folders 2, 3, and 4 for ClientName.exe found in ClientName.txt
2. If ClientName.exe is found, delete ClientName.exe
3. Copy NewExe.exe to location of former ClientName.exe
4. Rename new NewExe.exe to ClientName.exe that was being used in Step 1

---

Basically, what I am trying to do, is upgrade the EXE used by my clients across the board with one batch file as opposed to spelling everything out or having multiple batch files due to the multiple directories.

This is probably very easy.

Here is my current batch file (I copy and paste it, changing the EXE name each time):

```
DEL "ClientImport01\ClientName.exe"
COPY "FileServer\NewExe.exe" "ClientImport01\ClientName.exe"
```

Comment: Have you considered powershell instead?

Comment: Not really...I'm even more raw with PS than I am with batch...but I've worked with it. I'm just not very good with loops, etc. It's been more than a decade since I've taken any type of programming class in school. @JamesBlond

Comment: Why do you want to delete the file first, why not just override it if it already exists? You should be able to use the /Y flag.

Comment: In addition: When you update your exe, are there existing client exes that should not get updated, or are you updating all of them?

Comment: I supposed I could just overwrite. I prefer a complete rewrite for S&G's and that's how I've always done it...and I'm replacing all EXE's in the 3 directories that match. They are usually named ClientName_ProductName.exe. @JamesBlond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using @JamesBlond 's help, I created a powershell script with three separate functions, and called each function. The code is as follows:

```
function CopyEXE {

    cd C:\Temp\BatchTest #Go to your work folder

    $destination = @("C:\Test\")    #The locations to check

    $filePostfix = '_ProductName.exe';    #Your file postfix like '_ProductName.exe'
    $sourceFile = 'ProductName.exe';      #Your source file that replaces all existing client apps like 'ProductName.exe'

    $clients = get-content ClientName.txt; #Get all the names from your text file
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Checking Server"
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host 'Clients found in client file:' -foregroundcolor cyan;
    Write-Host $clients;
    Write-Host ""

    #Loop through all the names, lookup the location and overwrite the file

    $clients | ForEach-Object  {
        $fullName = $_ + $filePostfix;
        $location = Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Recurse -Filter $fullName;
        Write-Host 'Client app found: ' $location.FullName -foregroundcolor yellow;
        Copy $sourceFile $location.FullName -Force
        }
    }

CopyExe
```

So I have the following functions:

- CopyEXE
- CopyEXE2
- CopyEXE3

...and all three have a different $destination variable ($destination, $destination2, $destination3)...

The only issue is if a file does not exist in the destination, it gives the 'can't write over itself message', but that's just a minor nuisance more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a powershell script that I wrote. Please give it a go and let me know if it works for you. I'm sure this is doable with batch, but it's probably a pain.

```
cd C:\Temp\BatchTest #Go to your work folder

$filePostfix = '_ProductName.exe';    #Your file postfix like '_ProductName.exe'
$sourceFile = 'ProductName.exe'; #Your source file that replaces all existing client apps like 'ProductName.exe'

$clients = get-content ClientName.txt; #Get all the names from your text file
Write-Host 'Clients found in client file:' -foregroundcolor cyan;
Write-Host $clients;
Write-Host

#Loop through all the names, lookup the location and overwrite the file
$clients | ForEach-Object  {
    $fullName = $_ + $filePostfix;
    $location = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Recurse -Filter $fullName;
    Write-Host 'Client app found: ' $location.FullName -foregroundcolor yellow;
    Copy $sourceFile $location.FullName -Force
}
```

PS You could make this a lot shorter, but I guess like this it's more readable.

Comment: Hey @JamesBlond, I have tried the script and replaced the necessary values and got the following error:

     Client app found: Copy-Item : Cannot copy item C:\Users\user\Desktop\TFProAdmins\Live\TFProAdmin.exe onto itself. At C:\Users\user\Desktop\TFProAdmins\Live\TFProCopy.ps1:25 char:9+     Copy <<<<  $sourceFile $location.FullName -Force    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\us...\TFProAdmin.exe:String) [Copy-Item], IOException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: The message says 'Cannot copy item ... onto itself', so what values did you change and to what? Is there maybe an empty line in your ClientName.txt file? Does the application name really have an _ in-between the client name and the app name?

Comment: Sorry, I had the _TFProAdmin.exe at the end of each client name in the ClientName.txt file. I removed that, and it's working great. One thing though, each of the folders with the client files resides on 3 different servers...I don't think your script will look anywhere but the working directory. Do you know of a way where I can have it check 3 different network locations for the names/files? @JamesBlond

Comment: Would I just have three 'functions' in the powershell script, each having a different working directory?

Comment: Hi @JamesBlond, sorry to bother you, but any suggestions? I've tried to wrap your function in a 'foreach $dir in $destination' loop but it doesn't seem to be working very well. Gives me the original issue of trying to write the file on itself even though if I do a write-host $dir it shows me the directory properly.